# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown collection role - embedabble + criteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to create List of expressions for my elementCollection defined in an embeddable using the criteria builder, but it's always throwing:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown collection role: be.fgov.health.gift.action.domain.potentialdonorfile.patient.GeneralPatientInformation.causesOfDeath
```

Has anyone got any idea to work around this problem?

This is my code:

The entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POTENTIAL_DONOR_FILE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = Domain.SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME, sequenceName = "PDF_SEQUENCE")
//Domain contains the Id
public class PotentialDonorFile extends Domain {


    @Embedded
    private GeneralPatientInformation generalPatientInformation;

}

@Embeddable
public class GeneralPatientInformation {

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "CAUSES_OF_DEATH",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = PDF_ID_JOIN_COLUMN_NAME))
    @Column(name = "CAUSE_OF_DEATH")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<CauseOfDeath> causesOfDeath;

}
```

The repository layer :

```
Expression<List<CauseOfDeath>> listExpression = getGeneralPatientInformationPath(potentialDonorFileRoot).get(GeneralPatientInformation_.causesOfDeath);

private Path<GeneralPatientInformation> getGeneralPatientInformationPath(Root<PotentialDonorFile> potentialDonorFileRoot) {
    return potentialDonorFileRoot.get(PotentialDonorFile_.generalPatientInformation);
}
```

So to summarize:

When i'm calling "`xxx.get(GeneralPatientInformation_.causesOfDeath);`" I'm getting the `MappingException`.

EDIT:

As test I've moved the `ElementCollection` to the `PotentialDonorFile` itself (so outside of the embeddable), and now it seems to be working.. Can't consider this as a solution, but put I've it here as an extra comment.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you fill a JIRA issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa